# Date to datetime conversion in JPA

Tags: java, oracle, datetime, jpa, jdbc

I see the value stored in Oracle DB as `19-JAN-13`. When I get the result via:

```
List list1 = getEntityManager().createQuery(query).getResultList()
```

I see a value `2013-01-19 07:03:49.0` instead of `2013-01-19 00:00:00.0` or `2013-01-19 23:59:59.9`.

I want to know why this is the case? Shouldn't the conversion of date to datetime default time to zero? The row was created at time `07:03:49.0` on 1st Jan 2013.

The accessors are defined as

```
@Column(name = "FREE_TRIAL_EXPIRY_DATE")
public Date getFreeTrialExpiryDate() {
    return freeTrialExpiryDate;
}
public void setFreeTrialExpiryDate(Date freeTrialExpiryDate) {
    this.freeTrialExpiryDate = freeTrialExpiryDate;
}
```

Comment: May bad. Omitted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, Oracle [Date](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i1847) type stores the value of date and time. Your Oracle tool happens to show only the date DD-MM-YYYY value.

You just have to output the format properly in your Java application to have the desired DD-MM-YYYY presentation.

The bottom line is Java is not making up time values.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle is always going to keep the time, that's just the way it is.  Oracle's 'DATE' includes the time to the second, it is not equivalent to a timeless java.sql.Date.

If you want the field to be a time-less date, then you need to specify truncation at the application level by annotating with:

`@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)`

on the entity.